# How to avoid null when formatting value

Tags: java, freemarker

```
${date?string('yyyy-MM-dd')}
```

if date is null, freemarker will raise a exception

here is a solution

```
<#if date??>${date?string('yyyy-MM-dd')}</#if>
```

but this code is ugly,is there any shortcut like  `${date!}` ?

Comment: Not that I know of.  I tend to hide the ugliness in a component or macro :)

Answer (score 10):

You can write

```
${(p.bd?string("dd/MM/yyyy"))!}
```